# Hugo dynamic decide "unsafe" <!-- raw HTML omitted -->

Tags: markdown, hugo

I use `goldmark` as the [format](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#list-of-content-formats).

And I know I can edit the [config.toml](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/#configure-markup) files to stop the behavior about `raw HTML omitted` with

```
[markup.goldmark.renderer]
    unsafe = true
```

My question is, can I use the setting above in the [front matter](https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter/#front-matter-formats) (not the `config.toml`)?

For example, If I have many markdown files and I want one of them applying `unsafe = true` and others are not, does it is possible?

If not, can you explain why there is a need for a special distinction under the **static site** and is it possible to be attacked because of this? (This is actually what I really care about; otherwise, I am very willing to directly set the whole domain to turn on the insecure mode so that markdown is more comprehensive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not sure about the risk of setting the unsafe equal true, then you can set it as the default(false) and then use the [shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/) to help you. for example,

I create a file `raw_html.html`

**layouts/shortcodes/raw_html.html**

```
{{.Inner}}
```

**my_demo.md**

```
## bootstrap color
{{< raw_html >}}
<p class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">.bg-primary</p>
<p class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">.bg-secondary</p>
{{< /raw_html >}}

## inside link
brabrabra {{<raw_html>}}<a name="my_color">nice color</a>{{</raw_html>}} foo foo

[go to nice-color](#my_color)

## table
| {{<raw_html>}}<div style="width:64px">name</div>{{</raw_html>}} | Description |
| ---- | ---- |
| xxxxx| OOOOO|
```

output

```html
<head> <!-- the head is extra code for getting the bootstrap style -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<h2 id="bootstrap-color">bootstrap color</h2>
<p class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">.bg-primary</p>
<p class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">.bg-secondary</p>
<h2 id="inside-link">inside link</h2>
<p>brabrabra <a name="my_color">nice color</a> foo foo</p>
<a href="#my_color">go to nice-color</a>
<h2 id="table">table</h2>
<table><thead><tr><th><div style="width:64px">name</div></th>
<th>Description</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>xxxxx</td><td>OOOOO</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: "Can unsafe mode be applied partially, i.e. in the front matter in Hugo?"

No, it is not (and should not be) possible to define unsafeHTML in front matter. Allowing content creators to override the [security model](https://gohugo.io/about/security-model/#web-application-security) would be self-defeating.