# How to wrap raw HTML blocks in markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc, hugo, hugo-shortcode, pypandoc

Here is the example markdown code that I'm getting from pandoc:

```
### Header

Paragraph

- Item
- Item

<table>
//COMPLEX TABLE WITH NESTED CELLS GOES HERE AS RAW HTML//
</table>

Paragraph
```

The markdown file will be used with Hugo, so I need to wrap all raw HTML blocks with `{{< rawhtml >}}`. So, the output I'm looking for is:

```
### Header

Paragraph

- Item
- Item

{{< rawhtml >}}
<table>
//COMPLEX TABLE WITH NESTED CELLS GOES HERE AS RAW HTML//
</table>
{{< /rawhtml >}}

Paragraph
```

I can do it using regex. But is there an easier / more elegant way? Maybe pandoc filters?

Comment: You can allow HTML in the Goldmark markdown parser, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434800/hugo-dynamic-decide-unsafe-raw-html-omitted. That way this wrapping won't be required.